# javascript va;lidation dropdown value checkbox disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Good day,

The goal

When a specific value selected from dropdown change prop or attrib from checkbox.

Example where I am now. I would like when orange is selected to have box 1 disabled and have 2&3 enabled, when apple is selected enable box 1 and disable box 2&3 etc...

Thank You

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1"/>1:</td>
           <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="2"/>2:</td>
                   <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="3"/>3:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="CheckThis" name="CHeckThis" onchange="setChkSelect(this.value);">
                <option value="null">--Select This--</option>
                <option value="orange">orange</option>
                <option value="apple">apple</option>
                <option value="grappe">grappe</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

function setChkSelect(value){

```
var chk1 = document.getElementById('1')
chk1.disabled = (value == 'orange');

var chk2 = document.getElementById('2')
    chk2.disabled = (value == 'apple');
    chk1.disabled = (value == 'apple');

  var chk3 = document.getElementById('3')
      chk3.disabled = (value == 'grappe');
      chk1.disabled = (value == 'grappe');
```

}

Comment: I think you can't user number as a ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method would be preferable for your requirement.

```
function setChkSelect(){
   var ddl = document.getElementById('CheckThis');
   var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

   var chk1 = document.getElementById('1');
   var chk2 = document.getElementById('2');
   var chk3 = document.getElementById('3');

   if(selectedValue == 'orange'){
      chk1.disabled = true;
      chk2.disabled = false;
      chk3.disabled = false;
   }else if(selectedValue == 'apple'){
      chk1.disabled = false;
      chk2.disabled = true;
      chk3.disabled = true;
   }else if(selectedValue == 'grappe'){
      chk1.disabled = true;
      chk2.disabled = false;
      chk3.disabled = true;
   }else{
      chk1.disabled = false;
      chk2.disabled = false;
      chk3.disabled = false;
   }
}
```

Call this method as:

```
<select id="CheckThis" name="CHeckThis" onChange="setChkSelect();">
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/95w59/

Comment: Mention not! I have further modified this method for the case of orange. Confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no property named `enabled`

only `disabled`. work only with it

Comment: I modified the javascript part but not the result I expect, when apple is selected only 1 checkbox is disabled

Comment: This answer did provide understanding but did not resolve the question